# Generic Tree Structure - How to populate an org chart

Tags: c#, linq, generics, tree

I have what should be a fairly trivial problem but I want to make sure I'm doing this in the most "elegant" way possible in .Net 4.5 and I'd like some opinions from people smarter than me.

I have a class that represents a generic tree structure as such:

```
   public class TreeNode<T>
    {
        List<TreeNode<T>> Children;

        T Item {get;set;}

        public TreeNode (T item)
        {
            Item = item;
        }

        public TreeNode<T> AddChild(T item)
        {
            TreeNode<T> nodeItem = new TreeNode<T>(item);
            Children.Add(nodeItem);
            return nodeItem;
        }
    }
```

Now, I have a Person class that represents an employee of the organization.  Each `Person` object has an `ID` and a `BossID` that points to their superior.

Multiple employees can have the same boss, hence why I am trying to create an organization chart with this tree structure.

The top node is going to be the `Person` object where `BossID` is null (it's an `int?`).  That I can quickly get with LINQ.

It's the next step that is puzzling me a bit.  There are multiple approaches but they seem somewhat sloppy to me and I know there must be a much easier/elegant way to fill in the rest of the org chart.

So right now I have a generic object of `List<Person>` holding all the employees, with their various `BossID`s and this generic tree structure that I can add child nodes to.

It's all very basic, but what is the proper sequence to fill the tree?  Am I recursively supposed to iterate down the line?  I know there is backtracking involved here, which is where I'm getting stumped.

I apologize, my background is not in Computer Science, and if it was I realize that tree structures, linked lists, and everything else is trivial stuff.  But this is my first attempt and I want to see how it's done properly.

I appreciate any guidance.

Comment: So basically your question is how to create org tree given that you have list of people?

Comment: It's as simple as that.  I have that generic tree class, I have a List<> of People objects with their own IDs and their Boss's ID.  I just want to know what the cleanest approach under 4.5 would be.  I know I can look up how to fill a tree but there are some very poor examples out there, just looking for input.   I've seen some amazing magic around here, especially with things like LINQ ... that have greatly simplified code for me.

Answer (score 2):

So, given you have a `Person` class defined as this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID;
    public int? BossID;
}
```

...and you have a `List<Person>` defined as `people` then this works:

```
var lookup = people.ToLookup(p => p.BossID);

Action<TreeNode<Person>> addChildren = null;
addChildren = p =>
{
    foreach (var child in lookup[p.Item.ID])
    {
        var childNode = p.AddChild(child);
        addChildren(childNode);
    }
};

var trees =
    from boss in lookup[null]
    select new TreeNode<Person>(boss);

foreach (var tree in trees)
{
    addChildren(tree);
}
```

This assumes that you may have more than one person with a `null` boss. If you don't that's fine, just run this code and do `trees.First()`.

The definition of `TreeNode<T>` I used was this:

```
public class TreeNode<T>
{
    private List<TreeNode<T>> Children;

    public T Item { get; set; }

    public TreeNode(T item)
    {
        this.Item = item;
        this.Children = new List<TreeNode<T>>();
    }

    public TreeNode<T> AddChild(T item)
    {
        var nodeItem = new TreeNode<T>(item);
        this.Children.Add(nodeItem);
        return nodeItem;
    }
}
```

You could shorten `TreeNode<T>` to this though:

```
public class TreeNode<T> : List<TreeNode<T>>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }

    public TreeNode(T item)
    {
        this.Item = item;
    }
}
```

...then your need to modify `addChildren` to this:

```
Action<TreeNode<Person>> addChildren = null;
addChildren = p =>
{
    foreach (var child in lookup[p.Item.ID])
    {
        var childNode = new TreeNode<Person>(child);
        p.Add(childNode);
        addChildren(childNode);
    }
};
```

...but then you'd have all of the standard `List<>` operators available for `TreeNode<T>`.

Comment: @Patrick - If you know for sure that there's only one boss then do `var boss = trees.First();`.

Comment: In the case only one boss should exist a Single/SingleOrDefault would be even better since after this you would know if an error in your data exists as only one boss is allowed

Comment: @Enigmativity I am using your code in a new method that accepts a single parameter, all of the people (`List<Person> people`).  `people.Count` equals 25 at the start.  It is not working as expected.  The line 'foreach (var tree in trees)` enters the loop once, calling `addChildren(tree);` where `tree.Count = 0`.  I'm not sure exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @Patrick The line `foreach (var child in lookup[p.Item.ID])` is unsafe and will fail for leaf nodes. You can replace it with `var children = lookup[p.Item.ID]; if (children == null) return; foreach (var child in children)`

Comment: @IvanStoev - No, it's not unsafe. It returns an empty enumerable, not `null`.

Comment: @Patrick - There's no call to `addChildren(tree)`. It's `addChildren(childNode)`.

Comment: @Enigmativity You are right, didn't know that. Then the code should work w/o problem.